# TypeORM with MySQL - save object with large longtext fails

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I have a simple table in mysql:

```
create table if not exists images
(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    data longtext not null,
    metaData json not null,
    created timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
}
```

I can insert images up to around 3 MB without any problems:

```
// private imageRepository: Repository<Image>
...
const savedImage: Image = await this.imageRepository.save(image);  // 'imageRepository' is the TypeORM repository
```

Trying to save larger images results in this error message:

```
(node:8764) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: QueryFailedError: read ECONNRESET
```

Any idea how to fix this problem?  Maybe I missed it, but the TypeORM docu does not provide any help.

Comment: Could you run `show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'` on mysql

Comment: @Spikie:  max_allowed_packet -> 4194304

Comment: So your mysql the maximum size of one packet allowed is 4mb, are you sure the images you inserted is up to 3mb.

Comment: Well, I just tested up to 3 MB.  The next image I had for testing was 6 MB, which failed.  But what is the solution? Increasing packet size?

Comment: Yes, increase ```max_allowed_packet```. 3 mb is too small for your situation.

Comment: Do you mind turning your comment into a response so I can set it as the answer?

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, I just had a day off on saturday.Sorry for replied you late

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Spikie's comments this is the solution:

See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html

`max_allowed_packet` is a MySQL variable that needs to be set on the server and the client side to a number that is large enough to accommodate the largest desired blob size to store.  In my case it was set to 4.194.304, which means that the largest block I was able to store was around 4MB. After increasing this value to something around 20Mb I was able to store images up to around 20MB.